# 9 wire universal motor

Tags: universal-motor

So I found an old washing machine and salvaged the motor. However I can't find any information about how to wire it because it has 9 wires coming out. 
So 2 of them are speed control = 7 to go. 
2 are brushes and that leaves 5 for windings which seems like a lot.

[image]

This picture shows the inside where there are to connections in the top and one at the bottom. Also the two whites are connected and I don't know what they are supposed to do.

[image]

This picture shows the outside wires. I will explain what I have done as it has actually run already. I will number them 1-9 starting from the top.

2&3 are brushes. 
7&8 are speed control
5&6 were connected before I touched it

I did the following:

Connected 1&2
Set power on 3&4
Leaving 9 which goes inside, unused in the setup.

The motor ran but it leaves me wondering what the two whites connected inside does as well as wire nr 9 which I didn't use.

Can anyone help?

Update:

[image]

Here is some information about it if it could help. I've searched a lot for a datasheet on it I've been unable to find anything so far.

Thx for the answers so far.

Comment: This is a difficult question, and the answer would help only a person with doubts about the same motor (even so, you didnt informed the motor or the machine brand). Most of what can be said here is about the method to get a solution: 1) you should make observations about where each wires connects inside the machine; 2) probe the wires with a continuity tester, and also with a multimeter (ohm meter), trying to identify the different coils. 3) if there's a combination of connections that makes the motor run, start it and measure the voltages in the unconnected wires.

Comment: From your photos, the white wires go to a thermofuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some possibilities. They should be verified by testing with an ohmmeter, tracing wires etc. Speed may be controlled by shorting some of the field windings or connecting more or less of the field coil in series with the armature. One or more temperature switches inside the motor may protect from overheating. They may be connected to an external relay rather than cutting off power directly. The motor is reversed by changing which of the two brushes is connected to the field and the power source. There may be a wire for connecting the frame of the motor to protective earth ground.

Comment: I can't find any wire which seems connected to the frame, but I guess I can securely connect one to the frame myself and then connect that to ground? Also if that connection which is left is not connected but it runs can I then leave it as is and use it?

Comment: If you have found a connection that works, it is probably safe to use the motor. However the motor may not be protected from overload. Also, the motor speed vs. torque curve may be different with another connection. The motor label does not show a current rating. The current rating of the appliance might be a good indication of the safe operating current of the motor.

Answer (score 1):

little late, but here is wiring of motor, just wire count is inverted.

Just search motor model 1243098

http://ala-paavola.fi/jaakko/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=597en_145.pdf

**(edited)** The table lines about this motor are:

[image: excerpt from table]

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this is some thermo switch, because it was connected in serial with the brush, I think.

Comment: Valery - Welcome :-) Your posting was flagged, as it's very difficult to apply what it says. Can you improve your answer, please, by doing an [Edit] to add more detail? For example, what is "this" in your posting, when you say "*this is some thermo switch*"? And why do you believe that? Thanks!

Comment: Post the nameplate information, it sounds like a 3 phase motor.